# Why MSI afterburner greyed out my core voltage option?

Tags: msi-afterburner

This is the screenshot

[image]

The core voltage (mV) is greyed out. I can't undervoltage my card.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the feature:

> 1. Go to Settings
> 2. Enable `Voltage Control`
> 3. Restart Afterburner
>
> If its greyed out, that card may not allow the voltage to be adjusted

[EVGA GTX480 SSC + Afterburner, voltages grayed out?](https://hardforum.com/threads/evga-gtx480-ssc-afterburner-voltages-grayed-out.1548539/)